# xcode cannot assign value of type.. to NSSet

Tags: swift, core-data

I am working on CoreData with Swift 3 and I am almost done. I did the CoreData entities and now I am trying to save data from a form on the app and I got this error:

```
  import UIKit
  import CoreData

  class ItemDetailsVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate,          UIPickerViewDataSource  {

@IBOutlet weak var storePicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleField: CustomTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var priceField: CustomTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var detailsField: CustomTextField!

var stores = [Store]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    storePicker.delegate = self
    storePicker.dataSource = self



func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    let store = stores[row]
    return store.name
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return stores.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    // update
}

func getStores() {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Store> = Store.fetchRequest()

    do {
        self.stores = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        self.storePicker.reloadAllComponents()

    } catch {
        // some code
    }

}

@IBAction func savePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let item = Item(context: context)

    if let title = titleField.text {
        item.title = title
    }

    if let price = priceField.text {
        item.price = (price as NSString).doubleValue
    }

    if let details = detailsField.text {
        item.details = details
    }

   item.toStore = stores[storePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] error:    cannot assign value of type 'Store' to value of type NSSet?

}
```

I am not asking anyone to solve the error, I just wanna know what the error is telling me to do. Error is on the item.toStore = stores[storePicker... line

Comment: I don't know why its not showing the image

Comment: Please add the source code as text and the error to the question. Make sure all the custom types you are using that are relevant to the error are included.

Comment: Post your code as text instead of as an image. That way people can test your code more easily.

Comment: Im sorry I am new to stackoverflow so it might look a little messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your entity has one-to-many relationship, if you want to fix this issue try to change it "to one". I know you don't want the answer but here is the hint on how you can fix this. If you go to your *.xcdatamodeld file and locate your Item entity you can see the attributes relationships...find appropriate relationship and modify it from "to-many" to "to-one"

Comment: This is not an answer. Sure, does it solve the error msg issue? Yes. Is it an accurate answer to someone who needs a To Many relationship between CoreData entities? No.

Answer (score 6):

When you set a relationship on CoreData model to To Many it starts behaving like an Array. And like so you need to append the data to that array instead of assigning an class to it. You can do so with:

```
.addingObjects(from: [Any])
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am not asking anyone to solve the error, I just wanna know what the
>   error is telling me to do.

From what I have understood is that `toStore` is a `to many` relationship from `Item` to `Store` entity in CoreData.

Now since you need to know about the error only ,if I am correct and the relationship is exactly above then it means that `Item` entity has a `set` of stores associated with it not a single `Store` , hence you are getting this error

> error:    cannot assign value of type 'Store' to value of type NSSet?